# How can i display value of the type by the adress with WinDbg?

Tags: windbg

I have a pointer on some variable, lets say 0xffffffff`ffffff77 of struct Foo type. How can i display it value with WinDbg?

```
dt 0xffffffff`ffffff77
Symbol not found at address ffffffffffffff77.
```

Not works for me..

Comment: You can do `dds 0xffffffffffffff77` but really you have to know/guess the datatype in order for the output to make any sense: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542790(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you have the pdbs then you can do `dt Foo 0xffffffffffffff77` or `dt Foo. 0xffffffffffffff77` should work, otherwise you'd have to know  the type and then do `dds` like I suggested

Comment: If you have set a breakpoint and this value is local then `dv` will dump the local values and if you the pdbs loaded then you can just do `dt Foo.mVar 0xffffffffffffff77` I think should work

Comment: accepted. works. thanks!

Comment: Shall I post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that it cannot find the symbols so set your symbol path correctly using the GUI or `.sympath + mySymbols` and then reload `.reload`

Now you should be able to do this:

```
dt Foo 0xffffffff`ffffff77
```

or

```
dt Foo. 0xffffffff`ffffff77
```

should work, otherwise you'd have to know the type and then do `dds` like I suggested

another strategy is to set a breakpoint and when hit, if it is a local variable you should be able to dump this using `dv`, it should then recognise commands like:

```
dt Foo.mVar 0xffffffff`ffffff77
```

Answer (score 0):

Ln address - find nearest symbol
Dt symbol - show variable'